# Make a reusable GroupBy function

Tags: c#, grouping

I want to make a grouping function, that could be reusable by many others.
Here is a concrete example :

I made a function to group by `Numero`

```
public static List<Meb> GroupByNumber(this List<Meb> listMeb)
{
    return listMeb.GroupBy(x => new { x.Numero })
        .Select(cl => new Meb
        {
            ID = -1,
            IdUser = cl.First().IdUser,
            Barre = cl.First().Barre,
            CNC = cl.First().CNC,
            // ... and so long
        }).OrderBy(x => x.Numero).ThenBy(x => x.Avancement).ToList();
}
```

Then another grouping by `CNC`

```
public static List<Meb> GroupByCNC(this List<Meb> listMeb)
{
    return listMeb.GroupBy(x => new { x.CNC })
        .Select(cl => new Meb
        {
            ID = -1,
            IdUser = cl.First().IdUser,
            Barre = cl.First().Barre,
            CNC = cl.First().CNC,
            // ... and so long
        }).OrderBy(x => x.Numero).ThenBy(x => x.Avancement).ToList();
}
```

The problem is in the group function, I have a lot of attributes following (around 40).
So, when I want to change the way I want to make grouping (evolution of code), I need to do it in each GroupBy function. (I also can have many sometimes).

So, I'm looking a way I could write the function only once, then call it changing only the `GroupBy(x => new { x.Numero })` part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Enumerable.GroupBy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.groupby?view=net-7.0) takes a `Func<TSource, TKey>` as keyselector.

Make your function accept such an argument too:

```
public static <TKey> List<Meb> GroupMeb(
    this List<Meb> listMeb,
    Func<Meb,TKey> keySelector)
{
    return listMeb.GroupBy(keySelector)
        .Select(cl => new Meb
        {
            ID = -1,
            IdUser = cl.First().IdUser,
            Barre = cl.First().Barre,
            CNC = cl.First().CNC,
            // ... and so long
        }).OrderBy(x => x.Numero).ThenBy(x => x.Avancement).ToList();
}
```

Usage:

```
yourList.GroupMeb(x => new { x.CNC })
```

Comment: Great thanks, also can make it with several filters in group.

Answer (score 2):

I see two options.

1. Make your own version of `GroupBy()` that also does the mapping and ordering:

```cs
public static List<Meb> MyGroupBy<TKey>(
    this List<Meb> mebs,
    Func<Meb, TKey> groupBy)
    => mebs
        .GroupBy(groupBy)
        .Select(cl => new Meb
        {
            // ...and so on
        })
        .OrderBy(x => x.Numero).ThenBy(x => x.Avancement)
        .ToList();
```

Usage:

```cs
myList
    .MyGroupBy(x => x.CNC)
```

2. Extract the mapping and ordering into a reusable function and use the standard `GroupBy()`:

```cs
public static IEnumerable<Meb> MapAndOrder<TKey>(
    this IEnumerable<IGrouping<TKey, Meb>> mebs)
    => mebs
        .Select(cl => new Meb
        {
            // ...and so on
        })
        .OrderBy(x => x.Numero).ThenBy(x => x.Avancement);
```

Usage:

```cs
myList
    .GroupBy(x => x.CNC)
    .MapAndOrder()
    .ToList()
```

It's a little more "duplication" but it's also more modular IMHO.

Note that `MapAndOrder()` now receives an `IEnumerable<IGrouping<TKey, Meb>>` and returns an `IEnumerable<Meb>` instead.

Also be aware that there's no need to use `new { ... }` in a `GroupBy()` when you group by a single property.

You could take this even further by extracting the mapping into a function and creating a helper extension for your ordering:

```cs
public Meb MapMebGroup<TKey>(IGrouping<TKey, Meb> g) => new Meb
{
    // ...and so on
}

public static IEnumerable<Meb> WithDefaultOrdering(
    this IEnumerable<Meb> mebs)
    => mebs.OrderBy(x => x.Numero).ThenBy(x => x.Avancement);
```

Usage:

```cs
myList
    .GroupBy(x => x.CNC)
    .Select(MapMebGroup)
    .WithDefaultOrdering()
    .ToList();
```

Again, this looks like duplication, but in reality you are splitting up your logic into reusable and composable functions/operators.

Comment: Thanks for answer, will try it right now. Then I know about unnecessary `new`, but sometimes I need to put more than one argument (forgot to specify that).

Comment: could I ask you please, to add possibility to put more than one `Func<Meb, TKey>`? Tried to replace in function by `List<Func<Meb, TKey>>`, but then could not manage to put several arguments when calling function.

Comment: @Siegfried.V Why you can't just call provided function in foreach?

Comment: @LazarĐorđević just curiousity. In fact I took the first option. But as this is something new to me, curious if it exists such possibility...

Comment: knittl answered to that. I guess I may accept his answer as he first answered?

Comment: @Siegfried.V sorry, just noticed that only the first version will work. My other proposals are incorrect and I'll have to fix them later.

Comment: @GoodNightNerdPride thanks anyway, I used the first one, cause to b ehonnest, the 2nd one, I didn't understand it. Thanks

Comment: @Siegfried.V no worries. Fixed it anyway ^^