# Duplicated linq query

Tags: c#, linq, select, expression, func

I have 2 almost identical linq queries and want to remove repeating code from it. The only difference is the extra property in the GroupBy depending on some true/false condition.

How can I conditionally group by in linq without repeating the code like below?

```
var allergensList = _context.RecipeAllergens
            .Where(x => x.ParentId == Id && x.AllergenId != null)
            .ToList();
 var allergens = new List<AllergenInfo>();
        

if (isRecipe)
{
    allergens = allergensList
        .GroupBy(x =>  new { x.AllergenName, x.AllergenIcon, x.AllergenMaycontains })
        .Select(a =>
        {
            var v = a.OrderBy(x => x.AllergenMaycontains).First();
            return new AllergenInfo
            {
                AllergenName = v.AllergenName,
                AllergenIcon = v.AllergenIcon,
                AllergenMayContain = v.AllergenMaycontains ?? false
            };
        })
        .ToList();
}
else
{
    allergens = allergensList
        .GroupBy(x =>  new { x.AllergenName, x.AllergenIcon })
        .Select(a =>
        {
            var v = a.OrderBy(x => x.AllergenMaycontains).First();
            return new AllergenInfo
            {
                AllergenName = v.AllergenName,
                AllergenIcon = v.AllergenIcon,
                AllergenMayContain = v.AllergenMaycontains ?? false
            };
        })
        .ToList();
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Make a reusable GroupBy function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74178095/make-a-reusable-groupby-function)

Comment: It is not easy because there actually isn't any exactly common code: the type of `a` is different in the two queries, and thus the type of `v` is also different. You could however create a generic (extension?) method to combine the `GroupBy` and `Select`, passing in the key expression.

Answer (score 1):

You can left grouping by `x.AllergenMaycontains` but under condition

```cs
allergens = allergensList
    .GroupBy(x =>  new { x.AllergenName, x.AllergenIcon, AllergenMaycontains = isRecipe ? x.AllergenMaycontains : false })
    .Select(a =>
    {
        var v = a.OrderBy(x => x.AllergenMaycontains).First();
        return new AllergenInfo
        {
            AllergenName = v.AllergenName,
            AllergenIcon = v.AllergenIcon,
            AllergenMayContain = v.AllergenMaycontains ?? false
        };
    })
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Nice combining of the key expressions.